# Snowflake Id implementation

Tags: c#, algorithm, multithreading, locking, lock-free

For some time now I have maintained (and written) [IdGen](https://github.com/RobThree/IdGen). It's inspired by [Twitter's Snowflake project](https://github.com/twitter/snowflake) and it's intended use is to generate (roughly) incremental id's in a distributed scenario with multiple machines/processes/threads guaranteeing unique id's (no collisions). The way IdGen works is described in the [README](https://github.com/RobThree/IdGen/blob/master/README.md). But the algorithm, in general, works like this: it generates 64 bit id's (63 actually, to avoid the MSB and sorting issues on some systems). It does this by "partitioning" the 64 bits into a timestamp part, a "generator id" part and a sequence part.

A "generator" can be a machine or thread or process for example. The sequence is incremented as long as the timestamp part is equal to the previous timestamp of the last generated ID. Whenever the timestamp increments the sequence is reset to 0. My specific implementation allows the user of the library to configure how much bits he/she wants to use for each of the 3 parts that make up an id but that is not relevant for my questions.

My question today is about the [`CreateId()`](https://github.com/RobThree/IdGen/blob/306ba56bd12981313747c8009776582a8f6b65db/IdGen/IdGenerator.cs#L180) method.

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates a new Id.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>Returns an Id based on the <see cref="IdGenerator"/>'s epoch, generatorid and sequence.</returns>
/// <exception cref="InvalidSystemClockException">Thrown when clock going backwards is detected.</exception>
/// <exception cref="SequenceOverflowException">Thrown when sequence overflows.</exception>
public long CreateId()
{
    lock (_genlock)
    {
        // Determine "timeslot" and make sure it's >= last timeslot (if any)
        var ticks = GetTicks();
        var timestamp = ticks & MASK_TIME;
        if (timestamp < _lastgen || ticks < 0)
            throw new InvalidSystemClockException($"Clock moved backwards or wrapped around. Refusing to generate id for {_lastgen - timestamp} ticks");

        // If we're in the same "timeslot" as previous time we generated an Id, up the sequence number
        if (timestamp == _lastgen)
        {
            if (_sequence < MASK_SEQUENCE)
                _sequence++;
            else
                throw new SequenceOverflowException("Sequence overflow. Refusing to generate id for rest of tick");
        }
        else // If we're in a new(er) "timeslot", so we can reset the sequence and store the new(er) "timeslot"
        {
            _sequence = 0;
            _lastgen = timestamp;
        }

        unchecked
        {
            // Build id by shifting all bits into their place
            return (timestamp << SHIFT_TIME)
                + (_generatorId << SHIFT_GENERATOR)
                + _sequence;
        }
    }
```

Code not posted here is `GetTicks()` which, basically, returns a timestamp as integer but it's implementation is irrelevant.

My questions specifically are about if this code does what it's supposed to do in a multi-threaded scenario and about optimization.

First thing I do is take a lock and do all the work within that lock. There are two instance variables (`_sequence` and `_lastgen`) that are modified within this method. The `_generatorid` is only read. Besides implementing this method in a [lock-free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm) fashion (which I might do, sometime), I'm wondering if using [`Interlocked.Increment`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.increment?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [`Interlocked.CompareExchange`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.compareexchange?view=netframework-4.7.2) could help me make this code perform better. I could move some parts of the code within the lock outside of it but I don't think that would improve performance much (if at all). Another idea might be using another lock like a `ReaderWriterLockSlim` or `Monitor`?

I also wonder if there's ways I didn't think of myself to optimize this code besides the lock without sacrificing too much readability or the general idea.

And lastly, I wonder if there are any glaring bugs in here that I may have overlooked. Since this library is becoming more and more used I'd hate for it to have a bug in it's most important piece of code.

Feedback is much appreciated.

---

As per request, the entire class is as follows. Please keep in mind I'm not looking for feedback on the rest; I really want to focus on the `CreateId()` method and multithreading.

```
#if !NETSTANDARD2_0 && !NETCOREAPP2_0
using IdGen.Configuration;
#endif
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace IdGen
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Generates Id's inspired by Twitter's (late) Snowflake project.
    /// </summary>
    public class IdGenerator : IIdGenerator<long>
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the default epoch.
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DateTime DefaultEpoch = new DateTime(2015, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

        private static readonly ITimeSource defaulttimesource = new DefaultTimeSource(DefaultEpoch);
        private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, IdGenerator> _namedgenerators = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, IdGenerator>();

        private int _sequence = 0;
        private long _lastgen = -1;
        private readonly long _generatorId;

        private readonly long MASK_SEQUENCE;
        private readonly long MASK_TIME;
        private readonly long MASK_GENERATOR;

        private readonly int SHIFT_TIME;
        private readonly int SHIFT_GENERATOR;


        // Object to lock() on while generating Id's
        private readonly object _genlock = new object();

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the Id of the generator.
        /// </summary>
        public int Id { get { return (int)_generatorId; } }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the epoch for the <see cref="IdGenerator"/>.
        /// </summary>
        public DateTimeOffset Epoch { get { return TimeSource.Epoch; } }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the <see cref="MaskConfig"/> for the <see cref="IdGenerator"/>.
        /// </summary>
        public MaskConfig MaskConfig { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the <see cref="ITimeSource"/> for the <see cref="IdGenerator"/>.
        /// </summary>
        public ITimeSource TimeSource { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="IdGenerator"/> class, 2015-01-01 0:00:00Z is used as default 
        /// epoch and the <see cref="P:IdGen.MaskConfig.Default"/> value is used for the <see cref="MaskConfig"/>. The
        /// <see cref="DefaultTimeSource"/> is used to retrieve timestamp information.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="generatorId">The Id of the generator.</param>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentOutOfRangeException">Thrown when GeneratorId exceeds maximum value.</exception>
        public IdGenerator(int generatorId)
            : this(generatorId, DefaultEpoch) { }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="IdGenerator"/> class. The <see cref="P:IdGen.MaskConfig.Default"/> 
        /// value is used for the <see cref="MaskConfig"/>.  The <see cref="DefaultTimeSource"/> is used to retrieve
        /// timestamp information.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="generatorId">The Id of the generator.</param>
        /// <param name="epoch">The Epoch of the generator.</param>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentOutOfRangeException">
        /// Thrown when GeneratorId exceeds maximum value or epoch in future.
        /// </exception>
        public IdGenerator(int generatorId, DateTimeOffset epoch)
            : this(generatorId, epoch, MaskConfig.Default) { }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="IdGenerator"/> class.  The <see cref="DefaultTimeSource"/> is
        /// used to retrieve timestamp information.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="generatorId">The Id of the generator.</param>
        /// <param name="maskConfig">The <see cref="MaskConfig"/> of the generator.</param>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">Thrown when maskConfig is null.</exception>
        /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException">Thrown when maskConfig defines a non-63 bit bitmask.</exception>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentOutOfRangeException">
        /// Thrown when GeneratorId or Sequence masks are >31 bit, GeneratorId exceeds maximum value or epoch in future.
        /// </exception>
        public IdGenerator(int generatorId, MaskConfig maskConfig)
            : this(generatorId, maskConfig, new DefaultTimeSource(DefaultEpoch)) { }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="IdGenerator"/> class.  The <see cref="DefaultTimeSource"/> is
        /// used to retrieve timestamp information.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="generatorId">The Id of the generator.</param>
        /// <param name="epoch">The Epoch of the generator.</param>
        /// <param name="maskConfig">The <see cref="MaskConfig"/> of the generator.</param>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">Thrown when maskConfig is null.</exception>
        /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException">Thrown when maskConfig defines a non-63 bit bitmask.</exception>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentOutOfRangeException">
        /// Thrown when GeneratorId or Sequence masks are >31 bit, GeneratorId exceeds maximum value or epoch in future.
        /// </exception>
        public IdGenerator(int generatorId, DateTimeOffset epoch, MaskConfig maskConfig)
            : this(generatorId, maskConfig, new DefaultTimeSource(epoch)) { }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="IdGenerator"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="generatorId">The Id of the generator.</param>
        /// <param name="timeSource">The time-source to use when acquiring time data.</param>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">Thrown when either maskConfig or timeSource is null.</exception>
        /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException">Thrown when maskConfig defines a non-63 bit bitmask.</exception>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentOutOfRangeException">
        /// Thrown when GeneratorId or Sequence masks are >31 bit, GeneratorId exceeds maximum value or epoch in future.
        /// </exception>
        public IdGenerator(int generatorId, ITimeSource timeSource)
            : this(generatorId, MaskConfig.Default, timeSource) { }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="IdGenerator"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="generatorId">The Id of the generator.</param>
        /// <param name="maskConfig">The <see cref="MaskConfig"/> of the generator.</param>
        /// <param name="timeSource">The time-source to use when acquiring time data.</param>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">Thrown when either maskConfig or timeSource is null.</exception>
        /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException">Thrown when maskConfig defines a non-63 bit bitmask.</exception>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentOutOfRangeException">
        /// Thrown when GeneratorId or Sequence masks are >31 bit, GeneratorId exceeds maximum value or epoch in future.
        /// </exception>
        public IdGenerator(int generatorId, MaskConfig maskConfig, ITimeSource timeSource)
        {
            if (maskConfig == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("maskConfig");

#pragma warning disable IDE0016
            if (timeSource == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("timeSource");
#pragma warning restore IDE0016

            if (maskConfig.TotalBits != 63)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Number of bits used to generate Id's is not equal to 63");

            if (maskConfig.GeneratorIdBits > 31)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("GeneratorId cannot have more than 31 bits");

            if (maskConfig.SequenceBits > 31)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Sequence cannot have more than 31 bits");

            // Precalculate some values
            MASK_TIME = GetMask(maskConfig.TimestampBits);
            MASK_GENERATOR = GetMask(maskConfig.GeneratorIdBits);
            MASK_SEQUENCE = GetMask(maskConfig.SequenceBits);

            if (generatorId < 0 || generatorId > MASK_GENERATOR)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException($"GeneratorId must be between 0 and {MASK_GENERATOR} (inclusive).");

            SHIFT_TIME = maskConfig.GeneratorIdBits + maskConfig.SequenceBits;
            SHIFT_GENERATOR = maskConfig.SequenceBits;

            // Store instance specific values
            MaskConfig = maskConfig;
            TimeSource = timeSource;
            _generatorId = generatorId;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new Id.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Returns an Id based on the <see cref="IdGenerator"/>'s epoch, generatorid and sequence.</returns>
        /// <exception cref="InvalidSystemClockException">Thrown when clock going backwards is detected.</exception>
        /// <exception cref="SequenceOverflowException">Thrown when sequence overflows.</exception>
        public long CreateId()
        {
            lock (_genlock)
            {
                // Determine "timeslot" and make sure it's >= last timeslot (if any)
                var ticks = GetTicks();
                var timestamp = ticks & MASK_TIME;
                if (timestamp < _lastgen || ticks < 0)
                    throw new InvalidSystemClockException($"Clock moved backwards or wrapped around. Refusing to generate id for {_lastgen - timestamp} ticks");

                // If we're in the same "timeslot" as previous time we generated an Id, up the sequence number
                if (timestamp == _lastgen)
                {
                    if (_sequence < MASK_SEQUENCE)
                        _sequence++;
                    else
                        throw new SequenceOverflowException("Sequence overflow. Refusing to generate id for rest of tick");
                }
                else // If we're in a new(er) "timeslot", so we can reset the sequence and store the new(er) "timeslot"
                {
                    _sequence = 0;
                    _lastgen = timestamp;
                }

                unchecked
                {
                    // Build id by shifting all bits into their place
                    return (timestamp << SHIFT_TIME)
                        + (_generatorId << SHIFT_GENERATOR)
                        + _sequence;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns information about an Id such as the sequence number, generator id and date/time the Id was generated
        /// based on the current mask config of the generator.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="id">The Id to extract information from.</param>
        /// <returns>Returns an <see cref="ID" /> that contains information about the 'decoded' Id.</returns>
        /// <remarks>
        /// IMPORTANT: note that this method relies on the mask config and timesource; if the id was generated with a 
        /// diffferent mask config and/or timesource than the current one the 'decoded' ID will NOT contain correct 
        /// information.
        /// </remarks>
        public ID FromId(long id)
        {
            // Deconstruct Id by unshifting the bits into the proper parts
            return ID.Create(
                (int)(id & MASK_SEQUENCE),
                (int)((id >> SHIFT_GENERATOR) & MASK_GENERATOR),
                TimeSource.Epoch.Add(TimeSpan.FromTicks(((id >> SHIFT_TIME) & MASK_TIME) * TimeSource.TickDuration.Ticks))
            );
        }

#if !NETSTANDARD2_0 && !NETCOREAPP2_0
        /// <summary>
        /// Returns an instance of an <see cref="IdGenerator"/> based on the values in the corresponding idGenerator
        /// element in the idGenSection of the configuration file. The <see cref="DefaultTimeSource"/> is used to
        /// retrieve timestamp information.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="name">The name of the <see cref="IdGenerator"/> in the idGenSection.</param>
        /// <returns>An instance of an <see cref="IdGenerator"/> based on the values in the corresponding idGenerator
        /// element in the idGenSection of the configuration file.</returns>
        /// <remarks>
        /// When the <see cref="IdGenerator"/> doesn't exist it is created; any consequent calls to this method with
        /// the same name will return the same instance.
        /// </remarks>
        public static IdGenerator GetFromConfig(string name)
        {
            var result = _namedgenerators.GetOrAdd(name, (n) =>
            {
                var idgenerators = (ConfigurationManager.GetSection(IdGeneratorsSection.SectionName) as IdGeneratorsSection).IdGenerators;
                var idgen = idgenerators.OfType<IdGeneratorElement>().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name.Equals(n));
                if (idgen != null)
                {
                    var ts = idgen.TickDuration == TimeSpan.Zero ? defaulttimesource : new DefaultTimeSource(idgen.Epoch, idgen.TickDuration);
                    return new IdGenerator(idgen.Id, new MaskConfig(idgen.TimestampBits, idgen.GeneratorIdBits, idgen.SequenceBits), ts);
                }

                throw new KeyNotFoundException();
            });

            return result;
        }
#endif

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the number of ticks since the <see cref="ITimeSource"/>'s epoch.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Returns the number of ticks since the <see cref="ITimeSource"/>'s epoch.</returns>
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        private long GetTicks()
        {
            return TimeSource.GetTicks();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a bitmask masking out the desired number of bits; a bitmask of 2 returns 000...000011, a bitmask of
        /// 5 returns 000...011111.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="bits">The number of bits to mask.</param>
        /// <returns>Returns the desired bitmask.</returns>
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        private static long GetMask(byte bits)
        {
            return (1L << bits) - 1;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a 'never ending' stream of Id's.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>A 'never ending' stream of Id's.</returns>
        private IEnumerable<long> IdStream()
        {
            while (true)
                yield return CreateId();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns an enumerator that iterates over Id's.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>An <see cref="IEnumerator&lt;T&gt;"/> object that can be used to iterate over Id's.</returns>
        public IEnumerator<long> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return IdStream().GetEnumerator();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns an enumerator that iterates over Id's.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>An <see cref="IEnumerator"/> object that can be used to iterate over Id's.</returns>
        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to include more code because currently there are many undefined variables. It'd be great if you added the entire class.

Comment: The entire class is [linked](https://github.com/RobThree/IdGen/blob/306ba56bd12981313747c8009776582a8f6b65db/IdGen/IdGenerator.cs#L180) (the CreateId is clickable in the question). I was hoping to focus on this method only and not on the other parts of the class. That's why I didn't post the rest. I'll edit in the entire class. Also; the the people downvoting: let me know **why** you're downvoting.

Comment: I was the one who donvoted because of the lack of context. Now that you've improved the question and added missing parts I'll flip my vote.

Answer (score 3):

Since your lock only needs to protect the member variables you mutate, you can scope it to just that if/else block where you make your modifications.  You do use `_sequence` one additional time when generating the return value, but that could use a local copy acquired while the lock is held.  So the main thing you are moving outside the `lock` block is the call to `GetTicks()`.

If you can figure out how to implement this with Interlocked functions, that's going to be the best performance.  I'm not an expert, but I don't think you can do it directly, you would probably have to pack your sequence and generation into a single long.  A ReaderWriterLockSlim offers more functionality than you need - you have no readers - so it's likely not optimal.  You'll want to measure, but out of all the locks I'd guess you'd get the best performance from a SpinLock.

There's a whole use case you mention where these things are allocated per-thread, where presumably you don't want to pay for any thread safety overhead.  I would suggest moving the code that requires locking into a separate virtual function with no thread-safety mechanisms, and making a subclass that overrides the implementation in a thread-safe way.  This could be as simple as:

```
protected override long Increment()
{
    lock (_genlock)
    {
         return base.Increment();
    }
}
```